# Growth rate of the summation of $i.i.d.$ random variables with only $(1+\epsilon)$-th moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have $n$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ with zero mean and $\mathbb E[X_1^{1+\epsilon}] < \infty$, where $\epsilon$ is a constant real number in $(0,1)$. Let $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Can we say anything about the convergence rate of $S_n/n$? The law of large numbers tells us $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely and in $L^1$, but that is all I know.

If $X_i$ has a finite second moment, then the convergence rate is $O_p(n^{-0.5})$. If $X_i$ has a regular-varying tail (e.g. with density $|f(x)|\sim x^{-2+\epsilon}$), then I can use the generalized central limit theorem for stable distribution, so $S_n/n$ is $O_p(n^{-\epsilon/ 1+\epsilon})$ . However, I wonder if there is any general result when we only know the existence of $(1+\epsilon)$-th moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question the Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund Theorem is useful(cf.
Y. S. Chow & H. Teicher, *Probability Theory*, 3Ed, Springer Verlag, 1997, p.125, Theorem 2.5.2). It said that if $ {X_n} $ are i.i.d. r.v.s with zero mean, $ \mathsf{E}|X_n|^{1+\varepsilon}<\infty $, then
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{S_n}{n^{1/(1+\varepsilon)}}\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}0.\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
From (1),
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{S_n}{n}=\frac{S_n}{n^{1/(1+\varepsilon)}} \frac{1}{n^{\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon)}}=o(n^{-\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon)}) \quad 
 \text{a.s.}.
\end{equation*}
This is required result.